# difference between post and get

Tags: http, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

What is the difference between post and get request(http)? Okey,may be safer to Post but google(searcihig),yandex(searcihig),facebook,youtube(searcihig) and the others have been using Get. Why have they been using Get request although of the security vulnerability ?